# Event sourcing - delete event related files

Tags: event-sourcing

I'd like to store some of my data in relative big files (a few GBs per file). I'd like to use event sourcing and save events related to these files, e.g. FileCreated: title, description, timestamp, author, personal, encryptionkey, etc. After a while some of the files won't be needed any longer, and they take up a lot of space. So in order to free up space, I need to delete them. Doing so is problematic, because I will have the history in the event storage, but not the file in the filesystem. Is there any way to keep integrity and somehow delete both? Or is there a best practice for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I did not get an answer, I try to answer this myself.

It is possible to remove an event from the history, you need to create a new event storage and filter the events for the same aggregate id you want to get rid of. After you are done, you can switch to the new event storage and remove the old one. Probably you need to replay projections as well. So it is very similar to a whole migration, it takes a lot of time. In the current case it is not problem if I need to do this only once every year or so. Another problem with storing this data in the event storage that either I stream it from there or I need to duplicate it in order to serve it. The latter one is not always a good solution, because sometimes it takes too much time to copy and in order to save the data you need to stream it anyways, otherwise you will be out of memory very fast. So the event storage should support streaming attachments.

Another solution to keep the relative big data in the files and display something like 404 not found, or file was removed because this and that. I see this frequently. In this case it is ok to keep the event in the storage and for example you can add a ContentRemoved event, where you can select the cause. Another option to hide the removed file, so it won't be listed by the app, this is usual I guess too. This solution has drawbacks too. Migration is more complex with this approach, because you need to move both the event storage and the files. If you remove a file by accident, you cannot undo it later unless you have the file in the backup. This can be fixed by delaying the actual file removal with a few days, so you can undo it if you change your mind. Another option to make a trash and files will be deleted only by emptying the trash.

I think both solutions are worth to consider and probably it depends on the actual project which one is better suited.